# Number of iterations of a while loop

Tags: algorithms

I need to find out number of iterations this while loop will perform before terminating.

I have calculated  log(1000/n) and complexity is logb(n), is it correct?

```
while n <100,000
n←n×b
endwhile
```

Comment: What is the initial value of $n$ before the start of the loop? Is it $1$?

Comment: Yeah you can consider that

Comment: Since the value of $n$ changes during the loop, it doesn't make sense for it to show up in the formula for the complexity of the entire loop. It might make sense for the _starting_ value of $n$ to be in the formula if the loop is allowed to start from different initial values, but you would have to give that number its own name.

Comment: By the way, a step-by-step explanation of your reasoning could help. To fix the math notation, start here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to play a bit and see what values does $n$ takes?

$$n = 1 [=b^0]$$
$$n = b [=b^1]$$
$$n = b^2$$
$$\vdots$$
$$n = b^k [= 100, 000]$$

So $k = \log_b 100,000 = O(1)$ for reasonable $b$ (i.e. $b > 1$).